# Using text-indent with animate

Tags: jquery

following a JQuery tutorial, the instructor uses this code to rotate a menu button

```
$('#toggleMenu').animate({
    'text-indent':1
},{
    duration:1000,
    easing:'linear',
    step:function(now){
        $(this).css('transform', rortateZ(' + (now * 360) + 'deg)');    
    }
});
```

And then same code but with 'text-indent':0 to reverse the animation, the instructor said he is using 'text-indent' to be used with step function but I really dont understand, can you explain more the what is the role of 'text-indent' in this animation ?

Comment: Basically `text-indext` is a `html` property **which specifies the indentation of the first line in a text-block**. **[Know more](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_text-indent.asp)**

Comment: @putvande this place so people help each other, you are in the wrong place.

Comment: @GuruprasadRao I know that, but this is not answering my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The step callback provides a callback for each step in the animation. By animating a value from 0 to 1 the callback is invoked with the corresponding current value (0 to 1) that can then be directly applied to calculate the rotation degrees. Any property could be chosen instead of text-indent , but you want to use one that has no (or minimal) effect on the appearance of the element since its sole purpose is to provide the appropriate value for some other effect.